# Jasper Reports Groups and Columns

Tags: jasper-reports, grouping

Is there a way to change the Columns of a group based on a field?

I have the following dataset:
[Name, Type, Field]

Which I want it to show this kind of group for type = 1:

```
Name  Money
Bob   1 
Jen   2
```

For type = 2:

```
Name     Number of Cars
Clarkson 10
James    2
```

Is there a way to get the column to chance the text based on the field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change label If you're using a Java bean as a data source, I would recommend making `type` a String. When you go through and set values in the beans, you can check for `type == 1`, `type == 2`, etc. and set the String accordingly.

The only other way I can think to do it off the top of my head is to create 1 set of report objects for each type of data, and to create 3 templates, 1 per band, in iReport. Then you can show/hide report tables based on what you have data for. If you're not going to show all 3 datasets in 1 report, I recommend the first option as this way of doing things is too much work for what you'd be getting out of it.